# How to implement shallow array copy in mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I was used lodash function like that _.CloneDeep for object array copy
but I need shallow copy of this array
Please consider the following code:

```
 @observable.ref trades: Array<TradeType> = [];
 @action attachNewTrade = (trade: TradeType): Array<TradeType> => {
    let newTrades = _.CloneDeep(this.trades)
    newTrades.push(trade)
    this.trades = newTrades
  }
```

I am using React+Mobx in this project
Especially I need Observable function for this, not toJSON of immutable.js

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to mobx

```
 @observable.ref trades: Array<TradeType> = [];
 @action attachNewTrade = (trade: TradeType): Array<TradeType> => {
    this.trades = [...this.trades, trade]
 }
```

The reason you need to copy is that React can't detect internal change of objects/array, so you need to change the reference to notify React that something is changed.

If you want solution of more mobx way, please check [https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1489](http://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1489)

Comment: So this doesn't answer his question? He specifically asked for a mobx solution but a link is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I solved it with mobx's `toJS`: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html